# stop rendering of page untill API returns a response in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using React along with redux saga and i need to render the page only after the successfull response of an api call using saga. guys please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have come up with so far? What have you found on google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not hard. In your component render(), define the condition to render your content in this way:

```
render(){
  if (!this.props || this.props.userData == undefined) {
    return (
      <LoadingSpinner />
    );
  }else{
    return (
      <div className="page">{this.props.userData}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above example is to render the component when userData is ready.